# Change default/installed user information

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation

Often when I install a fresh copy of Windows (in the most recent case, Windows 7 Pro 64; also this computer is a member of a domain), I make the mistake of planning to simply delete the "initial" user that windows asks you to create. The most recent time, I've actually named the user "KILLME". Unfortunately, Windows basically seems to "register" the computer to this user, and uses the information from this user all over the place, and the name still shows up regularly even though I did delete the user.

Is there any way to change this information? I have searched through the registry, and I see "KILLME" in many different places, but I don't think it would be a good idea to just go around changing that phrase everywhere I see it.

Update: there are a lot of keys like the following:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\002F6F3CB7D697849BEE07C0C01ECFAD\InstallProperties\RegOwner`

A lot of keys have references to the path `C:\Users\KILLME\...` even though that path no longer exists.

This one in particular looks important and may be the one I would change to correct this:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOwner`

Comment: This is the first time I've heard anything of the sort. Please provide more details (i.e. specific registry locations) where you see these "remnants".

Comment: @Yehaw k I've added some info about particular registry keys